# Reload page with different anchor

Tags: jquery, hash, tabs, anchor, reload

Just got stuck with one problem. I have a page with Jquery UI tabs. Each tab can be accessed from different page by adding a hash tag to the link and it loads the page with the tab that I need. However, I also need to access different tabs within the same page. What I came up with is to add **target="_parent"** to the link with hash tag:

```
<a href="pictures.htm#tab2" target="_parent">
```

and it does what I need but only in IE. It reloads the page with different hash tag but for some reason Chrome and Firefox load the same tab every time. What I need is to create a **javascript function for the link which will fully reload the page with different hash tag**.

I came up with this code:

```
function gototab(reload)
   {
    window.location.href = 'pictures.htm#tab2';
    window.location.reload(true);
   }

<a href="pictures.htm#tab2" onclick="gototab();">open tab 2</a>
```

I feel like I almost closed it but something is wrong with my script. Can anybody help me to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just update `window.location.hash = '#tab2';` instead of the entire `href`.

Comment: Awesome! I new I was close. Thanks man!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function gototab(reload)
   {
    window.location.hash = '#tab2';
    window.location.reload(true);
   }

<a href="pictures.htm#tab2" onclick="gototab();">open tab 2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Blazemonger was a bit faster :)

Comment: That does not work in Chome, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me, latest version.