# Refresh the page and then go to a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, reload

How can I use javascript to reload page and go to a specific div when a button is clicked?

```
function reloadAgreement() {
  location.reload();
}

<li><a href="" onclick="reloadAgreement();">Return to Store Info</a></li>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function gototab(reload)
   {
    window.location.hash = '#tab2';
    window.location.reload(true);
 }
```

Return to Store Info

from here
[Reload page with different anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770741/reload-page-with-different-anchor)

edit:

To clarify, the section that says "#tab2" is the 'id' attribute of the div you want the page to go to when the link is clicked.